# Using knockoutjs data-bind on nested ul

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding, zurb-foundation

I tried to use a foreach data-bind on buttons. The button I tried to generate for each record have its own list of options thanks to the foundation split button.
The problem is that the inner ul doesn't access the correct item binded.

I wrote a little example program to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Try</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>



<h4 class="">persons</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: persons, as: 'person' }" class="inline-list">
    <li>
        <a class="small success round button split" data-bind="click: $parent.presentPerson"><h2 data-bind="text: person.name"></h2> <span data-dropdown="drop"></span></a><br>
        <ul id="drop" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.4.0rc.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Init foundation
    $(document).foundation();
    // This is a simple *viewmodel* - Java0Script that defines the data and behavior of your UI
    function AppViewModel() {
         var self = this;

        self.persons = ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'Bert', age: 30, hobbies :["music","computers"] },
            { name: 'Charles', age : 31, hobbies :["sports"] },
            { name: 'Denise', age: 32 , hobbies :["art", "fashion", "games"]}
        ]);


        self.removePerson = function() {
            self.persons.remove(this);
        };

        self.presentPerson = function () {
            var person = this;
            window.alert(person.name + " " + person.age);
        };
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on the button itself the person object is the correct one, clicking on the arrow and choosing remove will result in always removing the last object and not the chosen one.

Comment: I tried setting up an example, but can't understand the bug. Can you explain differently please:
http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/ez7bfmg9/

Comment: You need the zurb foundation library also so this example will work.
The problem is that clicking on each button works properly but clicking on the down arrow and afterward remove, always remove the last item and not the one clicked on.

Comment: After trying to reproduce the problem on your fiddle unsuccessfully,  I noticed the problem only occurs with the foundation library.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6d5jnL3r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid sharing one menu between all buttons, you need to have unique id's for them. In Knockout, we usually do that using `$index`.

In order for the DOM items to all be present in time for foundation's initialization, I moved the `foundation` call to after `ko.applyBindings`. It would probably be a good idea to make a custom binding handler that applies foundation to DOM items that get updated or whatever, but this was sufficient for this exercise.

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - Java0Script that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.persons = ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'Bert',
        age: 30,
        hobbies: ["music", "computers"]
    }, {
        name: 'Charles',
        age: 31,
        hobbies: ["sports"]
    }, {
        name: 'Denise',
        age: 32,
        hobbies: ["art", "fashion", "games"]
    }]);


    self.removePerson = function (data) {
        console.debug("Remove", data, this);
        self.persons.remove(this);
    };

    self.presentPerson = function () {
        var person = this;
        window.alert(person.name + " " + person.age);
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
// Init foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h4 class="">persons</h4>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: persons, as: 'person' }" class="inline-list">
    <li> <a class="small success round button split" data-bind="click: $parent.presentPerson"><h2 data-bind="text: person.name"></h2>
        <span data-bind="attr:{'data-dropdown': 'drop'+$index()}"></span></a>
        <ul data-bind="attr:{id: 'drop'+$index()}" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The remove menu item appears to be shared among the buttons, so the way to tell it which one it is affecting is to remember the last clicked.

```
var lastClicked;

self.removePerson = function () {
    self.persons.remove(lastClicked);
};

self.presentPerson = function () {
    var person = this;
    window.alert(person.name + " " + person.age);
    lastClicked = person;
};
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6d5jnL3r/1/).

Comment: First of all thanks for the response but I wrote this post to understand what is the problem between the inner ul with the data binding. Workarounds I already have but what I want is to understand the problem in the integration between the libraries. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that the widget shares the menu between the buttons.

Comment: I tried to solve that by binding between the name of the person to the id of the menu (The nested ul) + the data-dropdown attribute of the span but for some reason it didn't work...